# Shared Context between .NET Unit test Classes

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mstest

I understand that ideal unit tests should not share any context between them but I have a dilemma: I am trying to unit test against a piece of software that only has a single license that can be instantiated at a time.

`.NET` unit tests seem to run in parallel so when I click "Run all tests" the classes are all run simultaneously and most fail because they can't all have a license.

So I see two questions that are mutually exclusive:

- How do I share the context between C# unit testing classes?
- **OR** How do I force `.NET` unit tests to **NOT** run in parallel?

**Clarification:** *The licensed software is not what I'm trying to test, it's just the tool I need to DO the test*

Comment: You mean force them to *not* run in parallel?

Comment: Can you mock or inject your licensing provider so that it doesn't interfere with your unit tests?

Comment: It's sound like, you've created an Integration tests instead of UTs. Why don't you use a mocking framework for an isolation?

Comment: Sadly no. I need a fully functioning product since the tests do things that need an actual license. Otherwise, mocking would be the way to go for sure.

Comment: It does sound like an integration test but it's really a unit test. To clarify, the licensed software is not what I'm trying to test, it's just the tool I need to DO the test

Comment: It's not a unit test because you're testing multiple things in one test.  You've tightly coupled your software to your licensing mechanism and will have a very difficult time doing true unit tests.

Comment: are you use MsTests or NUnit as your test runner?

Comment: @Raychaser according to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee921484%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  set <Execution parallelTestCount="1"> in the test settings. another option is to change your test to be an [Ordered Tests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182630%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I'd consider [Singleton](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) an anti-pattern since it makes unit testing impossible. 
But this a good use case to have a [Singleton](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx).
A real singleton, with a private constructor and a static constructor, will run only once and will be thread-safe.

This way you can keep your tests running in parallel.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. I was hesitating but I think this is the way to go too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you might be looking for but would that work if you run all tests at the same time however each of them runs on a separate AppDomain?

For reference I used the cross domain delegates where you could pass your actual test: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.docallback(v=vs.110).aspx

Let me know if that's works!